# Display array values in a table

Tags: php, html, arrays, curl, html-table

I have the following code, which currently displays the array values in `resArr` and `resArr2` separately. I would like to display this data in a table, showing the value of array `resArr` in `column 1` and the value of `resArr2` in `column 2`. I have tried experimenting with `tr` and `td` however for some reason this has no effect on the output.

Could anyone provide me with any possible solution please?

```
$resArr = json_decode($res, 1);
$resArr2 = json_decode($res2, 1);
foreach ($resArr as $key => $value)
{
    echo "<tr>";
   if(!is_array($value))     
   {
       if($key == 'attire' or $key == 'category' or $key == 'location' or $key == 'name' or $key == 'website' or $key == 'checkins' or $key == 'likes')
        {
            echo "<td>";
            echo  $key . ':' . $value;
            echo "<br />\n";
            echo "</td>";
        }
   }
   echo "</tr>";
}

foreach ($resArr2 as $key => $value)
 {
   //to eliminate array to string conversion error 
   if(!is_array($value))     
   {
       if($key == 'attire' or $key == 'category' or $key == 'location' or $key == 'name' or $key == 'website' or $key == 'checkins' or $key == 'likes')
       {
           echo  $key . ':' . $value;
           echo "<br />\n";
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: You have to iterate through both arrays at the same time: One row(<tr>) will be created at each iteration and you'll add a new column in your loop when going from Arr1 to Arr2

Comment: can you show your expected output screenshot or a glimpse of result hers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive you want something like this:

```
$resArr = json_decode($res, 1);
$resArr2 = json_decode($res2, 1);
$labels = array('attire','category','location','name','website','checkins','likes');
$count1=0;

echo '<table border="1">';
echo '<tr><th>key</th><th>resArrLabel</th><th>resArr2Label</th></tr>';
foreach ($labels as $label)
{
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th>'.$label.'</th>';
        echo '<td>'.(array_key_exists($label, $resArr) ? $resArr[$label] : '').'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.(array_key_exists($label, $resArr2) ? $resArr2[$label] : '').'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

It was much faster becouse use only one loop and add th label to each column and row. Try to add more css style.

Comment: The table will still not appear using this method.

Comment: so try:
$resArr = json_decode($res, 1);
$resArr2 = json_decode($res2, 1);
var_dump($retArr);
var_dump($retArr2);
die();

and copy result into comment.

Comment: array(23) { ["id"]=> string(11) "10936503735" ["about"]=> string(73) "Welcome to http://asos.do/p3RFnb, where you’ll Discover Fashion Online."["category"]=> string(8) "Clothing" ["checkins"]=> int(2893) ["id"]=> string(17) "10152708202338736" } ["name"]=> string(4) "ASOS" ["parking"]=> array(3) {  ["website"]=> string(82) "http://asos.do/p3RFnb https://marketplace.asos.com/ http://fashionfinder.asos.com/" } array(1) { ["error"]=> array(3) { ["message"]=> string(50) "You must use https:// when passing an access token" ["type"]=> string(14) "OAuthException" ["code"]=> int(1) } }

Comment: This is only part of the array, had to delete some of it as it did not fit,however it should not make a difference. For some reason the output of resArr2 was not displayed. 


And I notice that I have an error in the end, however this was not effecting my output when I was not trying to display values in table

Comment: You must change something else in your code. Try to resolve error. You get data from url without using https protocol. Add https:// at the begin of your url. Output of resArr2 was not displayed becouse there is nothing to display.

Comment: I have come to the conclusion that the problem is the CSS in the PHP file, as I have tried the code in a blank page removing any types of CSS and extra HTML, and it works. 


Still figuring out what part of the CSS is ruining the table

Comment: Use some developer tools like firebug or native chrom which was display after click F12. Find your table in Elements tab and read all his style in Style subtab.

Comment: I have found the table using Elements Tab, and have the Style subTab open. What should I be looking for here?

Comment: "display: none" will be suspicious. You can turn off and on style by check and uncheck box next to them. Find which generate problem and then you have information in which file and line they was defined.

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate both arrays at the same time. Try this

```html
$resArr = json_decode($res, 1);
$resArr2 = json_decode($res2, 1);
$count1=0;

echo "<table border='1'>";
foreach ($resArr as $key => $value)
{
 echo "<tr>";
   if(!is_array($value))     
   {
    if($key == 'attire' or $key == 'category' or $key == 'location' or $key == 'name' or $key == 'website' or $key == 'checkins' or $key == 'likes')
  {
   echo "<td>";
   echo  $key . ':' . $value;
   echo "<br />\n";
   echo "</td>";
  }
   }
   
   $count2=0;
   foreach ($resArr2 as $key => $value)
   {
    if($count1==$count2){
   //to eliminate array to string conversion error 
   if(!is_array($value))     
   {
    if($key == 'attire' or $key == 'category' or $key == 'location' or $key == 'name' or $key == 'website' or $key == 'checkins' or $key == 'likes')
    {
     echo "<td>";
     echo  $key . ':' . $value;
     echo "<br />\n";
     echo "</td>";
    }
   }
    }
    $count2++;
  }
   echo "</tr>";
   $count1++;
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: The arrays are being iterated at the same time, however the table is not being displayed. 

The values are just being displayed according to the key

Comment: can you show your expected output screenshot or a glimpse of result hers?

Comment: I would like to have a table with rows and columns showing the key in the first column, the value of the first array in the second column, and the value of the second array in the third column. 


However no type of table is being displayed, only plain text

Comment: just add the table tag before and after the parent foreach loop. hope you will see the expected results.

Comment: I added this tag echo "<table>" before and after the foreach loop, however a table is still not being displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the results displayed for me. I am using sample array.

```html
$resArr = array('attire'=>'1','category'=>'2','location'=>'3');
$resArr2 = array('attire'=>'a','category'=>'b','location'=>'c');

echo "<table border='1'>";

$count1=0;
foreach ($resArr as $key => $value)
{
 echo "<tr>";
   if(!is_array($value))     
   {
    if($key == 'attire' or $key == 'category' or $key == 'location' or $key == 'name' or $key == 'website' or $key == 'checkins' or $key == 'likes')
  {
   echo "<td>";
   echo  $key . ':' . $value;
   echo "<br />\n";
   echo "</td>";
  }
   }
   
   $count2=0;
   foreach ($resArr2 as $key => $value)
   {
    if($count1==$count2){
   //to eliminate array to string conversion error 
   if(!is_array($value))     
   {
    if($key == 'attire' or $key == 'category' or $key == 'location' or $key == 'name' or $key == 'website' or $key == 'checkins' or $key == 'likes')
    {
     echo "<td>";
     echo  $key . ':' . $value;
     echo "<br />\n";
     echo "</td>";
    }
   }
    }
    $count2++;
  }
   echo "</tr>";
   $count1++;
}
echo "</table>";
```

[image: Here is the result generated by the above code]

Comment: This is exactly how I would like my code to be shown! I have copied the entire code, however still no table is being shown. 

Would that mean that the problem is in the array?

Comment: Yah, If this code is not working than make sure your array is correct by print_r($resArr); and print_r($resArr); and comment all the code below.

Comment: array(23) { ["id"]=> string(11) "10936503735" ["about"]=> string(73) "Welcome to asos.do/p3RFnb, where you’ll Discover Fashion Online."["category"]=> string(8) "Clothing" ["checkins"]=> int(2893) ["id"]=> string(17) "10152708202338736" } ["name"]=> string(4) "ASOS" ["parking"]=> array(3) { ["website"]=> string(82) "asos.do/p3RFnb marketplace.asos.com fashionfinder.asos.com/"; } array(1) { ["error"]=> array(3) { ["message"]=> string(50) "You must use https:// when passing an access token" ["type"]=> string(14) "OAuthException" ["code"]=> int(1) } }

Comment: do not dump just $resArr = json_decode($res, 1); print_r($resArr);
$resArr2 = json_decode($res2, 1);  print_r($resArr); die();